# Use jQuery only for one script (not interfering with other JS code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem, I have written some jQuery scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sshin').keyup(function () {
    var query = $(this).val();
    if(query != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {query: query},
        success: function (data) {
          $('#sshout').fadeIn();
          $('#sshout').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'article', function () {
    var text = $('#sshin').val();
    text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
    text += $(this).text();

    var uniq = text.match(/\b\w+\b/g).filter(function (el, idx, a) {
      return idx === a.lastIndexOf(el);
    });

    text = uniq.join(',');

    $('#sshin').val(text);
    $('#sshout').fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Of course in the `index.html` file I included the jQuery library and my JS code. Everything worked perfectly fine when I tested it without being included from another file.

My problem is now that my `index.html` is being included by another file (which I can't change at all) and apparently interferes with other JS, e.g. JQuery Code..

Is it possible to just use the jQuery library I included only for this script or or do you have any other ideas?

If you need any other information let me know.

Error Output:

```
slim.js:3 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
at chooseLinkContainer (slim.js:3)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (slim.js:3)
at k (slim.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (slim.js:2)
at Function.ready (slim.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.D (slim.js:2)

jquery-1.10.2.js:8672 
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

piwik.js:58 
Uncaught Error: A siteId must be given to add a new tracker
at K.addTracker (piwik.js:58)
at Object.addTracker (piwik.js:66)
at piwik.js:69
at piwik.js:69
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.10.2.js:612), <anonymous>:3:10)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery-1.10.2.js:612
at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.10.2.js:613)
at init.domManip (jquery-1.10.2.js:6281)
at init.append (jquery-1.10.2.js:6047)
```

Error Messages after i removed my Jquery Reference:

```
slim.js:2 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated
because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. 
For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.




piwik.js:58 
Uncaught Error: A siteId must be given to add a new tracker
at K.addTracker (piwik.js:58)
at Object.addTracker (piwik.js:66)
at piwik.js:69
at piwik.js:69
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (slim.js:2), <anonymous>:3:10)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at slim.js:2
at Function.globalEval (slim.js:2)
at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (slim.js:2)
at Function.each (slim.js:2)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you write it in Javascript, if you don't depend on jquery, this kind of thing can't happen.

Comment: Is it possible that you include the errors you are getting when you include the `index.html` in the other file, or at least some indication about what parts of JS and jQuery are overlapping?

Comment: It also depends on _how_ you are including the `index.html` file in the other file

Comment: @Pineda i edited the errors into my post

Comment: what do you mean by "included in another file?" referenced in an iframe? asynchronously loaded by script?

Comment: It's included over PHP and only the body tag will be included in the website

Comment: you may use javascript to load jquery in your code using this [solution](https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamically-load-jquery-library-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that You are using two versions of jQuery, one old one with `live` method which was removed in newest versions. Your jQuery is overwriting the previous one, but question is if jQuery exists then it is real need to add it again?

Few possible solutions:

1.Just remove second jQuery source ( leave there older with live method ) and add script after jQuery is appended to page, good place is somewhere in end of html tag.

---

2.If solution 1 not work use **noConflict** for added version ( right after it is appended to page ):

```
    var myJq = $.noConflict(true);
    function ( $ ){
      //your code
    }(myJq);
```

The second solution give possibility to use **$** sign inside local function scope without conflict with other files, in global scope newest jQuery will be in myJq variable.

Some more helpful information about using multiple jQuery on one page - [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

---

3.Remove second jQuery like in solution 1 and add Your code inside `window.onload` callback - it will be for sure after all scripts are loaded to page.

```
window.onload = function() {

  //code
};
```

Comment: i'm sorry to say but nothing of that worked ..://
i still get the error messages and yea..

Comment: After i removed the second JQuery Library Linking, i still get errors(less but still errors) and this warning message `Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience`

Comment: If so that only means the error will exists also if You will remove everything You have done, so this must be different problem there - independent from Your code.

Comment: If i remove my script(which is attached above), the errors are not there, so it has to do something with my code

Comment: "After i removed the second JQuery Library Linking" - You removed your added linking or that one which was there? You need to remove that one added by You.

Comment: Yeah the one i added is removed, sorry my english isn't the best

Comment: Can You paste error messages which appear after removing it - "i still get errors(less but still errors) a"

Comment: It's in the post now

Comment: @Damon sorry but Your jquery code can't have any influence on this error, it is something else here but I don't have a clue.

Comment: I thought the same but it kind of has to do with that..but still thanks for the help